# Is it possible to use Razor as a standalone library (without any asp.net business) on OSX (via Mono)

Tags: mono, razor, template-engine, monomac

I would like to write a proof of concept [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) app which renders html "Views" using c# and Razor.

Is this possible?

If not, does anyone recommend any other Templating engines that compare to the simplicity of Razor. I don't mind writing it in Objective-C if I have to, but Mono would be simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be interested in [this](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) project. You just have to download zip which consists of two DLLs, reference them in your project and examples like [these](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/wiki) just works. Have in mind that you have to make 4.0 project. I have been testing this on Mono 2.10.5, however OS was Linux, not OS X, because I don't have one. It shouldn't be a problem nevertheless.

Another approach is to do something like mentioned [here](http://thegsharp.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/using-razor-from-a-console-application/). Post is quite old and libraries' names has changed but you should be able to use one which are downloadable [here](http://gonzalo.name/blog/archive/2011/Jan-21.html). The first approach is cleaner, however I am not sure if it is what you need.

You can also find [this](http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/town-crier-an-open-source-e-mail-templating-engine-for-net/) project interesting.

Comment: +1 Thanks Konrad, just saw your answer, I'll follow the link and get back to you, thanks again

Comment: One thing to note about this approach is that you lose all access to any of the `Html` helpers that are provided with MVC. A lot of people don't realize this when they look into our RazorEngine.